# IBM Cloud Code Engine: How to determine app URL from environment?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, serverless, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I have a Python app deployed to [IBM Cloud Code Engine](https://ibm.com/cloud/code-engine). The app needs to determine its external URL for some security configuration. How can I obtain the app URL from the environment?

I looked at the [list of injected environment variables](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-application-workloads#inside-env-vars), but could not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just recently added some new environment variables to help with this. Depending on which region you're in they should be available today, but worst case by next week.

The new env vars you want to look for are:

- CE_APP: the application name
- CE_SUBDOMAIN: the subdomain (or kube namespace if you're interested) of the app/project
- CE_DOMAIN: the domain name of the app/project you're running in.

So the full URL would be:  `https://${CE_APP}.${CE_SUBDOMAIN}.${CE_DOMAIN}`

If you happen to be using JOBS then there's:

- CE_JOB: the job associated with the job run, if there is a Job
- CE_JOBRUN: the job run name

Comment: I see the new variables are mentioned in today's release notes: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-release#july21

Comment: @Doug: is it possible to change the CE_SUBDOMAIN since it is a env var?

Comment: @GiacomoBartoli I no longer work on Code Engine but I can try to answer. I believe the CE_SUBDOMAIN still maps to the K8s namespace used to host the app and it's static so can not be changed. I'm curious, why do you want to change it? If you're interested in changing the entire URL then this might be of interest: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-domain-mappings

Comment: @Doug just curiosity. I do not like personally that random string within the url:)

Comment: @GiacomoBartoli yep not much we can do about that right now - custom domains are the only choice available today